# Issues with calling a JavaScript function from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dialog

I have created a form to upload a a newsletter into the database. I'm using the iFrame method to post the date without the page refresh and I'm displaying a nice jQuery dialog for the loading.

I am now having issues with closing that dialog when the upload is complete. All the tutorials I have read online say that I must just echo out the code like this:

```
<?php
  echo "<script type='text/javascript>uploadComplete();</script>";
?>
```

Now the JavaScript does run when I do something stupid to test like just echo out an alert, but when I try and call any function or just go straight to the jQuery to close the dialog it just says that the function is not defined. I can post my code if it is necessary, but it's pretty standard and I didn't think I would need to in this kind of example.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still haven't figured it out.. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by using the following code:

```
<?php
  echo "<script type='text/javascript>top.uploadComplete();</script>";
?>
```

The "top" keyword just solved all of my problems. I hope this helps whoever has the same issue I had!

Answer (score 5):

you forgot `'` in the end of `'text/javascript'`

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>uploadComplete();</script>";
```

**NB** : the `type` attribute is entirely unnecessary if the script is JavaScript

Comment: Oh that's my bad, but the typo is fixed in my code and it doesn't work. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
using just php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'jsfunction();'
   , '</script>';

escaping from php mode to direct output mode

<?php
// some php stuff
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jsFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried both of these methods but it just wont find the function. And I have double checked the function names that they are correct.